# How to create a multiline navigation bar similar to the one in WhatsApp in iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Does anyone have a clue on how to create a multiline navigation/top bar in iOS? I want something similar to the status line in WhatsApp (the one that displays last seen or the current status information).
Any advice would be appreciated.

I want to achieve something like in the image (Francis Whitman / last seen [...]):

[image]

Comment: Make it easy for people to answer you... post a screenshot of the thing you are after instead of expecting people to download some random app.

Comment: @coneybeare sometimes I wonder if questions like this are simply thinly veiled attempts at astroturfing to get downloads for an App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a `UINavigationController` will use the `title` property of the currently-displayed view controller for the title in its navigation bar. You can have it display any arbitrary view, however, by setting the `titleView` property of the view controller’s `navigationItem` property, as so:

```
// In your view controller’s implementation (.m) file:
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName
               bundle:(NSStirng *)nibBundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];

    if (self) {
        UIView *myTitleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                                       0.0f,
                                                                       250.0f,
                                                                       44.0f)];
        [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

        [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:myTitleView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 200)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
[label setText:_certificate.name];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```